# How to get Netflix working?

Tags: netflix, netflix-desktop

Netflix is the only service that requires me to keep windows around. I've tried several times to install the netflix desktop but without success. Can't get it to work using chrome or firefox.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Ok. But we are a site dedicated to questions about fixing problems in Ubuntu; not to post a comment. If I see this: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/netflix-linux-html5-support-plugins this http://itsfoss.com/netflix-ubuntu-1404-desktop-app/ and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fx7X79Arvlc I would assume it would not be that hard. It has been a while since I installed 14.04 and netflix but I do not believe it took me more than 15 minutes(?)

Comment: I removed a large part of your post and made it a question. Hope you do not mind. Besides that: please try if my answer(use the link for a more detailed installation) gets you a working netflix.

Answer (score 3):

Netflix should be easy to install. From [omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/netflix-linux-html5-support-plugins) (more details on all the specifics for this in the link). A summary for installing Netflix:

**Prerequisites**

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS* or 14.10 Alpha
- Google Chrome Beta or Dev (v37+)
- An active Netflix subscription or trial
- Have ‘Prefer HTML5‘ selected in ‘Netflix Account > Playback’
- For 14.04 you also need to update `libnss3`.

And after installing these all you need to do is change the user agent string with these details (the link above uses a [user agent changer](http://www.omgchrome.com/user-agent-switcher-extension-for-chrome/) webapp for that):

- Name: Netflix Linux
- String: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2114.2 Safari/537.36
- Group: (is filled in automatically)
- Append?: Select ‘Replace’
- Flag: IE

It is a little bit more difficult than installing a package. But not so difficult that a Linux user would have trouble getting this up and running.